# handlebars registerHelper linking to HTML file

Tags: javascript, html, handlebars.js, registerhelper

I came across this piece of Javascript code which uses Handlebars.js and I would like to link this to my index.html page. Can anyone help with that?

Thanks!

This is the original code:

```
//replace URL by html link
Handlebars.registerHelper('link', function(text)  {
var exp = /((https?|ftp|file):\/\/[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%?=~_|!:,.;]*[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|])/ig
var exp2 = /(@[A-Za-z0-9]+)/ig
return new Handlebars.SafeString(text.replace(exp,'<a href="$1">$1</a>').replace())
})
```

Comment: Haven't tried it yet, don't really know how to... I'm reading the documentation but I'm really new to this so it doesn't make much sense to me... Will try though!

Comment: I've tried opening the example folder using MAMP and got a screen saying "Hello World!" and so on. I tried changing directory to my website folder and it keeps opening the example one... how do I uninstall this?

Answer (score 0):

Initially you need to include the handlerbars.js file in your HTML.

```
<script src="~/Scripts/handlebars-v2.0.0.js"></script>
```

Then

If you want to return the register Helper function named "link" inside a div then you can use it like this.

```
<div id="sample">{{link}}</div>
```

The output will be

```
<div id="sample"><a href="$1">$1</a></div>
```